# Actual JFrame size does not match with declared

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im using Java on MacOS. Actual screen resolution is 2560x1600. But JFrame with size 1200x900 or more doesnt fit into the screen.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(0,0,1200,900);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Furthermore this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(0,0,3000,3000);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + "x" + frame.getHeight());
```

outputs 1280x773. Why does this happen and how to deal with it?

EDIT: There is x2 scale. Might be because of retina and OS configurations. Looking for the way to change that scale.

Comment: `frame.setBounds(0,0,1200,900);` That's the first mistake. Don't guess the size of a frame. Either pack it to get the ideal size, or call [`Frame.setExtendedState](Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-) ..and this is the second mistake. `frame.setLayout(null);` I won't go into why, since we deal with it almost every day. Search [tag:null-layout-manager] for the details.

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) make frame to fill fully the screen, but its size is still 1280x773.

Comment: And ..where is the actual problem with that? The GUI should work with whatever space is has been assigned, using a scroll pane if necessary. Suck it up and move on.

Comment: The problem is i cant make frame size i need and dont get why

Comment: The results from setting the frame to 0,0,3000,3000 are not surprising;  the desktop has ultimate control over window sizes and positions, on all platforms, and is free to reject or alter any position or size request.  What exactly are you seeing when you set your Frame size to 1200×900?

Comment: I see all height and almost all width of the screen covered with this frame. Also i got that this probably happens because of retina. And it is twice bigger than it should be. Now Im wondering why and when this happens and how to handle that.

Comment: Unless you're running in full screen mode, there is a "menu bar" and on some systems, the dock to contend with, it's possible the system is disallowing windows which exceeded these bounds

Answer (score 0):

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //============ or   set Location to (0, 0) for this approach

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
    int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

    frame.setSize(width, height);
```

Comment: output: 1280x800. As it seems because of retina and some OS configurations scale is x2. And Im looking for the way to change that scale

Answer (score -1):

try to add frame.pack() to your code here is how you should type

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0,0,3000,3000);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

frame.pack();
        System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + "x" + frame.getHeight());

Comment: output: 80x24. Frame cant be smaller i think